# How do I get people to move in?

Tags: dungeon-village

I am playing Dungeon Village on Android, and built some vacant houses for adventurers to live in. Problem is, no one wants to live in my town!

What do I have to do to lure people in? I would love a town bustling with adventurers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each adventurer has a *satisfaction* stat (smiley face). This needs to be around at least 40-50 before they will consider moving into your town.

[image]

Satisfaction can be increased by giving them gifts, especially new equipment that is better than their old one. You can either buy it from the shop or send your adventurers on dungeon runs to find you more loot.

Answer (score 1):

Get the adventurer's satisfaction level to 40, and wait for a littl bit and there will be a pop-up telling to build a house for the adventurer to live in